# How to check if a string contains apostrophe

Tags: sas

I don't remember how SAS deal with these special characters. Any built-in functions?

E.g

`a = New Year's Day`, should I use something like `index(a, 'New Year's Day') > 0`?

Comment: you want to check if the string contains an apostrophe or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to this question is the masking of the apostrophe in quotes. If you wish to look for an occurrence of a single apostrophe, you can mask it with double apostrophes:

**Looking for single apostrophes**

```
data _NULL_;
  a="New Year's Day";
  b=index(a,"'");
  put b=;
run;
```

The single apostrophe is passed as a second argument to the index function, using double quotes.

**Looking for double quotes**

```
data _NULL_;
  a='They said, "Happy New Year!"';
  b=index(a,'"');
  put b=;
run;
```

This time around, the double quote is set inside single quotes when passed to the index function

Answer (score 3):

mjsqu and NeoMental covered the basic case well, but in the special case where you do not have the option of using `"` (for example, you need to prevent macro variable resolution), you can double the apostrophe:

```
data _null_;
  a='MerryXmas&HappyNewYear''s'; *here need single quotes or a macro quoting function;
  b=find(a,"'"); *here do not need to mask ampersand resolution;
run;
```

Of course you could also use `%nrstr` to avoid resolution, but there are real life cases where this is occasionally needed.  This works with `""` similarly (two `""` become one character `"`).

Answer (score 1):

Use "**find**" command like below to find out what are you looking for is there in the string or not. If the **returned value is greater than > 0** then apostrophe or whatever you are looking for is there, otherwise not.

- Teststring - where you want to look
- Next to Teststring is "'" - In quotes what are you looking for, in
  your case apostrophe

---

```
data _null_;
TestString="New year's day";
IsItThere=find(TestString,"'");
put IsItThere=;
run;
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002267763.htm